# Symfony2 - routing subdomains, but subdomain has a special directory

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I read a Google and Symfony2 docs about routing on Subdomains like:

```
acme_admin_separator:
    path:     /
    resource: "@AcmeAdminSeparatorBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host:     admin.{domain}
    requirements:
        domain: %domain%
```

But it should works only, if subdomains are handled by `.htaccess`. But I have this webhosting hierarchy:

```
+ /domain.com/
+-- /web/ <-- Here are all my Symfony2 files
+--- /app/
+--- /bundles/
+--- /src/
+--- ...
+-- /sub/ <-- directory for subdomains
+---- /admin/ <-- directory for admin.domain.com subdomain
```

And I'm asking - is it possible to configure routing to be able to use `admin.domain.com` as the route for my Symfony2 project without copying all my Symfony2 files to this folder? And if is, should I do something in `/admin/` directory?

Comment: Why is it that your subdomains are in a special directory?

Comment: i use this hierarchy because i use  other web applications in  subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Your route is right. You must to config your hosting or server for **handle all requests for non-existent subdomains `*.domain.com`**.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean exactly. I have a choice in my webhosting administration to configure subdomains which will not use /sub/ directory but will be handlel by .htaccess. But it is not good for me because I have subdomains which have normal content independently of my Symfony2 project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy app.php, and paste file in directory like this : `/sub/admin/` (change include path in app.php). Or make a blank file and include app.php.

Comment: So it will "clone" my project, am I correct? Also I'm not sure, if it's enough, .htaccess missing.

Comment: @Mr.Smith If you want to use symfony2 in your subdomain, you have to put in root path the .htaccess and the app.php like your first domain.